# Avoid empty lines in php checkbox

Tags: php, html

I have html form wherein 7 check box are there. When all the boxes are checked, it is giving good result. Whereas any body gives 3 or 4 check, it shows the result with empty lines in between. It looks very indecent. Any body can suggest the corrective code for that.

the HTML code for the check box:

```
CONDITIONS: <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="Invoice">Invoice <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="c2" value="LR copy">LR copy <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="c3" value="Test Reports">Test Reports<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="c4" value="Draft"> Draft<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="c5" value="Check-list">Check-List <br />
<input type="text" name="c6" placeholder=" Add any" maxlength="25" size="40"><br />
<input type="text" name="c7"  placeholder=" Add any clause"  maxlength="25" size="40">
```

the php code for the above check-box:

```
    <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

table { margin: 1em 0 0 0; border-collapse: collapse; }
td {margin: 5px 0 0 0;padding: .4em ;  border: 0px solid; height: 12px; }
tr td:first-child {font-weight: bold; width: 250px; color: black; height: 10px; font-size: 18px;}
tr td:last-child {width: 450px; color: blue;height: 10px; font-size: 18px; }

p {margin: 5px 0 0 20px; width: 700px; line height: 20px; text-align: justify; font-size:105%;
font-family: Arial, "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, sans-serif;}

#trim {margin: 5px 0 0 20px; width: 700px; line height: 20px; text-align: center; font-size:150%;
font-family: Arial, "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, sans-serif;}

.z{ margin: 5px 0 0 20px; width: 700px;}
.z1{ margin: 5px 0 0 20px; width: 700px;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="trim">
<b> FORMAT  </b>    
<hr size="2" noshade>                      
</div>


<?

$k1 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k1']);
$k2 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k2']);
$k3 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k3']);
$k4 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k4']);
$k5 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k5']);
$k6 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k6']);
$k7 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k7']);
$k22 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k22']);
$k23 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k23']);
$k8 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k8']);
$k9 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k9']);
$k10 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k10']);
$k11 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k11']);
$k12 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k12']);
$k13 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k13']);
$k14 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k14']);
$k15 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k15']);
$k16 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k16']);
$c6 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c6']);
$c7 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c7']);
$k19 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k19']);
$k20 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k20']);
$k21 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['k21']);
$r1 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['r1']);
$r2 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['r2']);
$r3 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['r3']);
$r4 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['r4']);
$r5 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['r5']);
$r6 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['r6']);
$r7 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['r7']);
$r8 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['r8']);
$r9 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['r9']);
$r10 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['r10']);
$c1 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c1']);
$c2 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c2']);
$c3 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c3']);
$c4 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c4']);
$c5 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c5']);

$c8 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c8']);
$c9 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c9']);
$c10 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c10']);
$c11 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c11']);
$c12 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c12']);
$c13 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c13']);
$c14 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c14']);
$c15 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c15']);
$c16 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c16']);
$c17 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c17']);
$c18 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c18']);
$c19 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c19']);
$c20 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c20']);
$c21 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c21']);
$c22 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c22']);
$c23 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c23']);
$c24 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c24']);
$c25 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['c25']);
$p1= strtoupper($_REQUEST['p1']);
$p2 = strtoupper($_REQUEST['p2']);

if(empty($k2)){$kk="  "; }else{$kk="(Code: $k2)";}


$html = "<p> <div class='z1'>
<b><u> PROJECT DETAILS </u></b>
<table>
<tr><td> Project Name: </td>  <td > $k1 &nbsp; &nbsp; $kk</td></tr>
<tr><td> Purchase Order no:</td> <td > $k3 &nbsp; &nbsp;Dtd: $k4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Total Order Value:</td>  <td >$k6 </td></tr>
<tr><td> Materials Ordered </td> <td >$k5 </td></tr>
<tr><td> Supplier Details: </td> <td >$k22  <br /> $k23</td></tr>
</table>
<br /><b><u> DISPATCH CONDITIONS </u></b>
<table>
<tr><td> Shipment from: </td> <td > $k11</td></tr>
<tr><td> Shipment to: </td> <td >$k12 </td></tr>
<tr><td> Dispatch starting date: </td> <td >$k9 </td></tr>
<tr><td> Last date of dispatch: </td> <td >$k10 </td></tr>
<tr><td> Part-Shipment: </td> <td >$r1 </td></tr>
<tr><td> Part-Transshipment: </td> <td > $r2</td></tr>
<tr><td> Transport Charges: </td> <td > $r4</td></tr>
<tr><td> Insurance Charges: </td> <td > $r3</td></tr>
<tr><td> Basis of price: </td> <td > $r5</td></tr>
</table>

<br /><b><u> BANK DETAILS </u></b>
<table>
<tr><td> L/C amount: </td> <td > $k8 <br /> Rs. $k30 </td></tr>
<tr><td> Usance period: </td> <td > $r9  Days from the date of dispatch.</td></tr>
<tr><td> Usance interest: </td> <td>$k15 Days to Supplier A/c. and  $k16 Days to Buyer A/c.</td></tr>
<tr><td> Usance interest charges:  </td> <td >Not more than $k14 % p.a </td></tr>
<tr><td> L/C Charges: </td> <td > Opening charges to $r7 and discount charges to $r8</td></tr>
<tr><td> Negotiation to be done: </td> <td > within $r10  Days from the date of dispatch.</td></tr>
<tr><td> Place of Expiry: </td> <td >  $k21</td></tr>
</table>

<br /><b><u> DOCUMENTS REQUIRED:</u></b>
<ul><li>$c1 
</li><li>$c2 
</li><li>$c3
</li><li>$c4 
</li><li>$c5 
</li><li>$c6
</li><li>$c7 
</li></ul>
<br /><b><u> L/C CONDITIONS </u></b>
<ul><li>
$c8 </li><li>
$c9 </li><li>
$c10</li><li>
$c11 </li><li>
$c12</li><li>
$c13 </li><li>
$c22 </li><li>
$c23 </li></ul>

<br /><b><u> ADDITIONAL CONDITIONS </u></b>
<ul><li>
$c14 </li><li>
$c15 </li><li>
$c16 </li><li>
$c17 </li><li>
$c18 </li><li>
$c19 </li><li>
$c20 </li><li>
$c21 </li><li>
$c24 </li><li>
$c25 </li><li>
$k19 </li><li>
$k20 </li></ul>

</div></p>";

$html .= "<div class='z'> <hr /> Place: <b>".$p1."</b></div>";
$html .= "<div class='z'> Date:  $p2 <div style='float:right;font-size: 12pt'><i> (Authorized Signature ) </i></div></div>";


print($html);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always echoing all the lines. when some values are empty, there will be just empty line (list item). So you have to check that the values exists. Little example:

```
    <?

    $html = '<p>CONDITIONS:</p><ul>';

    function echoRow(&$html, $val) {

      if (isset($val) && !empty($val))
        $html .= '<li>' . $val . '</li>';  
    }


    echoRow($c1);
    echoRow($c2);
    echoRow($c3);
    echoRow($c4);
    echoRow($c5);
    echoRow($c6);
    echoRow($c7);

    $html .= '</ul>';

    print($html);

?>
```

Comment: I have lot of HTML data inside the PHP code. And can't put echoRow, plz suggest print($html), if you can

Comment: Not getting what you mean..?? the `echoRow` is only helper function for to check the value and add it to `$html` variable. Then you just print it out for browser..

Comment: Got the code but still I have doubt. there is another check box with 12 values. If I use <ul> inside $html, it would not give correct results, instead of that is there any <ul clause >

Comment: the entire php code is given below. Could you correct it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because when a checkbox is not checked, then its value is not send to server. For example if C1 is not checked, then it is not send in $_POST  values.  What you can do is check if each of checkbox is set and display only those whose value exits. If you want you can show alternative message for checkbox that is not set. You can do something like this

```
    $html="<ul>";

    if(isset($c1))
          $html.="<li>$c1</li>"
    else 
    {
     //do nothing or show alternative message 
     $html.="<li>Invoice not selected</li>"
    }

// do same for $c2....$c7
$html.="</ul>";
print($html);
```